# JWPlayer.seek() causing jittery playback for rewind feature

Tags: jwplayer

I'm trying to make a rewind feature for the JWplayer. I'm using `player.seek(calcPosition())` to run the video backwards. The problem is, the `onSeek` event calls the `Play` function, or some other way sets the `onPlay` event to `"PLAYING"` which causes the JWplayer to try and run the video forward. This results in a jittery playback as my code tries to seek backwards and, the JWplayer tries to play forward. Is there any way to `seek()` without the JWPlayer trying to play forward?

Comment: JW Player can't "play the video backwards." It doesn't process the video in any way - it's just a steering script that feeds the video to the browser.

Comment: It would be a hack to overwrite this. You would have to set the player to pause() onPlay() or something.